# WPF - Binding custom DataGridTextColumn template's Content property to parent's property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templatebinding

First of, I am coming back to WPF after several years of leaving it behind, I knew a little of it before and develop a few windows but now I am beyond rusty.
I am trying to build a DataGrid with filter headers, now I understand that there isn't a ready made control for that and needs to be created, which I have started using a Template.

My template consists of a Label control to the left which contains the title of the header, and a DatePick control to the right which I will use as part of my filtering process. I am trying to get Label.Content property inside my template to pick the DataGridTextColumn.Header property value of template parent.

I have tried RelativeSource, TemplatedParent and everything else there is, I also couldn't find any post on here that described a similar issue to mine nor a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

My code

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControls.ReportsListingControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="600">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Grid Width="200" Height="35">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Width="50"
                               Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridTextColumn}}, Path=Header}" />
                        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Width="30" 
                                    BorderThickness="0" Text="" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle1}" Header="The Text I want displayed in my template label" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `DataContext` itself:

```
<Label ... Content="{Binding}" />
```

The `DataContext` of a `DataGridColumnHeader` is the `Header` object itself, i.e. the `string` in your case.